# How transaction is matched with read and write operations in BLOB storage (azure)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

In Azure Monitor, for particular blob in storage account we have the following metrics:

- ingress (GiB)
- engress (GiB)
- transactions (count)

It looks like:

[image]

I have a database which data and log files are using Azure Blob as storage and want to calculate the price of such scenario per month. Using the pricing calculator we have cost per storage (let's say 100 GB) and dynamic cost per the following operations:

[image]

My questions is one transaction in the Azure Monitor chart the same as one read/write operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions is one transaction in the Azure Monitor chart the same as one read/write operation?

Not necessarily, according to [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage-reference#transaction-metrics), which state:

> Transactions: The number of requests made to a storage service or the specified API operation. This number includes successful and failed requests, as well as requests that produced errors.

Since the interaction is via the API requests, there are various other calls which may impact that value. Additionally, since the call could specify more data that available to write or read a single disk (we don't know where it's stored, could be on a bunch of SD cards for all anyone knows) I don't think it's even safe to consider it as one request is one read or write, specifically.

Comment: It is very strange that the pricing is based I. read and write operations and there is no such metric in the monitor.